# vim over ssh: character q popping up

Tags: neovim

Whenever I ssh onto my remote machine and type `:` a `q` gets pre-filled. It does not, however quit when I press enter, it just replaces the colon with a , so below the status line there is a `qq`.

The machine uses the same .vimrc as my main computer where this behavior is absent ( as it should be ).

*Edit:* Seems to be a problem with neovim:

```
sudo su -
vim
: # -> :q in command line
```

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes

Seems when changing sessions to a different user or SSHing into a remote box the TERM get's unsupported